# Node Search and store function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to write a node script that will search for and grab all the code from a pattern from within in file in a directory/subdirectory and store the code with a the filename/location but seem to be having some trouble. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var migrationCode = [];
var migrationFiles = [];
var useDirectory = '.';

fs.readdir(useDirectory, function(err, files) {
    files.filter(function(file) {
        return file;
    })
    .forEach(function(file) {
        fs.readFile(file, 'utf-8', function(err, contents) {
            inspectFile(contents);
        });
    });

    function inspectFile(contents, filename) {
        var contents = contents;
        var pat = contents.match(/^\/\/.*\*custom\*(.|\n)*\*custom\*/g);
        if (contents.indexOf(pat) != -1) {
            for (var index in pat) {
                migrationFiles.push({migrationCode[index], filename});
            }
        }
    }

    if (err)
        throw err;

    for (var index in files) {
        this.inspectFile(file[contents], files[index]);
    }
});
```

Example Input from example-file.js

```
// *custom code*

all of this including comment above and below

// *custom code*

none of this
```

Example output (not variable specific to the script)

```
var exampleOutput = [{'captured code', 'example-file.js'}];
```

Comment: Can you provide example input and output?

Comment: What is the point of that `.filter`?

Comment: @Jamen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959462/in-node-js-reading-a-directory-of-html-files-and-searching-for-element-attribu

Comment: @Silicabello: Right, but you're not filtering anything.

Comment: My understanding is Im filtering useDirectory with the inspectFile function, but by all means feel free to correct the code